# InfluxDBClientError: retention policy not found: autogen

Tags: influxdb-python

I am going through https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-python-influxdb/ documentation to query influxdb with python.

I am able to create the database:

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
client.create_database('pyexample')
client.get_list_database() 
client.switch_database('pyexample')
```

Plus I am also sending data inside the database:

```
json_body = [
{
    "measurement": "brushEvents",
    "tags": {
        "user": "Carol",
        "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2f"
    },
    "time": "2018-03-28T8:01:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "duration": 127
    }
},
{
    "measurement": "brushEvents",
    "tags": {
        "user": "Carol",
        "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2f"
    },
    "time": "2018-03-29T8:04:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "duration": 132
    }
},
{
    "measurement": "brushEvents",
    "tags": {
        "user": "Carol",
        "brushId": "6c89f539-71c6-490d-a28d-6c5d84c0ee2f"
    },
    "time": "2018-03-30T8:02:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "duration": 129
    }
}
]
```

Invoking the json body as:

```
client.write_points(json_body)
True
```

But soon now, I want to query the metrics from the database with:

```
client.query('SELECT "duration" FROM "pyexample"."autogen"."brushEvents" WHERE time > now() - 4d GROUP BY "user"')
```

This query results in a error:

> File ipython-input-31-6e47204db16b, line 1, in module
>     client.query('SELECT "duration" FROM "pyexample"."autogen"."brushEvents"           WHERE time > now() - 4d GROUP BY "user"')
>
> File "/home/rahul/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 420, in query
>       in data.get('results', [])
>
> File "/home/rahul/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/resultset.py", line 25, in **init**
>       raise InfluxDBClientError(self.error)

```
InfluxDBClientError: retention policy not found: autogen
```

How can I get the query result ?

I checked the retention policy where also found error:

```
client.query('SHOW RETENTION POLICIES')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in 
>       client.query('SHOW RETENTION POLICIES')
>
> File "/home/rahul/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 409, in query
>       expected_response_code=expected_response_code
>
> File "/home/rahul/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 286, in request
>       raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
>
> InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"error parsing query: found EOF, expected ON at line 1, char 25"}

Comment: What do you get if you execute `client.query('SHOW RETENTION POLICIES')`?

Comment: @Stanko I added error generated by command `client.query('SHOW RETENTION POLICIES')` too in the main body of question.Kindly have a look

Comment: That error indicates you need to specifiy a database that you want to execute query on. Try: `client.query('SHOW RETENTION POLICIES ON pyexample')`

Comment: `client.query('SHOW RETENTION POLICIES ON pyexample')` works and gives following output 

`ResultSet({'(u'results', None)': [{u'duration': u'0', u'default': True, u'replicaN': 1, u'name': u'default'}]})`

How to modify now my query from database ?

Comment: Replacing `autogen` by `default` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `autogen` to `default`:

```
client.query('SELECT "duration" FROM "pyexample"."default"."brushEvents" WHERE time > now() - 4d GROUP BY "user"')
```

Comment: strange...It gives `Out[5]: ResultSet({})` as output. How output can be null.We are missing out here something @Stanko

Comment: It is good that you're not receiving an error that means the retention policy "default" is found so your first issue is solved. You do not get any results because of your `WHERE` condition. Look at the timestamps of your data they range from 2018-03-28 to 2018-03-30. In your `WHERE` condition you want to show data points where the time is after 4 days ago (`time > now() - 4d`). Run the query without the `WHERE`: `client.query('SELECT "duration" FROM "pyexample"."default"."brushEvents" GROUP BY "user"')`. That should yield you the 3 points grouped by the user.

Comment: Yes, the query worked and Thanks for explaining the retention policy concept. I got the idea. :)  @Stanko

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what error message you're getting. In my case, I got error "**retention policy not found: forever**" which translates to - *A retention policy named "forever" is not found*.

And I fixed it by:

- Enter InfluxDB docker container
- Launch `influx`
- `use collectd` to select database
- Create a new retention policy named "forever":
  `create retention policy "forever" on "collectd" duration 2d replication 1`

The official documentation can be found: [Manage retention policy](https://archive.docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/query_language/database_management/#retention-policy-management)

Comment: Calling a retention policy "forever" with a duration of 2 days might be a little misleading.